# TypeError: Fraction.__str__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, class, typeerror

Error:

```
TypeError: Fraction.__str__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Code:

```
class Fraction:

    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.n = numerator
        self.d = denominator

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.n}/{self.d}'

    __repr__ = __str__()

    def __add__(self, other):  # adding the numbers
        n = self.n * other.d + self.d * other.n
        d = self.d * other.d
        return Fraction(n, d)  # object at 0x000001F5E5E6BEB0 memory of the location object
```

Comment: You are trying to assign the return value of a *call* to `__str__`, rather than the function itself. `__repr__ = __str__`.

Comment: This can be avoided by just defining `__repr__`. If `__str__` isn't defined, `Fraction` will just inherit `object.__str__`, which does nothing except call `__repr__`.

Comment: However, `__repr__` *should* be defined to return somethign like `f'Fraction({self.d}, {self.n})'`, not the formatted string returned by `__str__`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to *call* `__str__` and assign its return value to `__repr__`. You want to assign the function itself:

```
__repr__ = __str__
```

However, `__repr__` should usually return something resembling Python code that could be used to reconstruct the  value, not necessarily the same value as `__str__`. Consider this instead:

```
class Fraction:

    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.n = numerator
        self.d = denominator

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.n}/{self.d}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Fraction({self.n}, {self.d})'

    def __add__(self, other):
        n = self.n * other.d + self.d * other.n
        d = self.d * other.d
        return Fraction(n, d)
```